# Shouldn't protect_from_forgery with: :exception raise an error if I don't include an authenticity token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's my understanding that `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` which is the default in Rails, will cause an error if forms are submitted and they don't have the `authenticity_token` input.

However it seems like this is not the case anymore. This is a Rails 5 app, and I've mostly done Rails 4 in the past, so I wonder if something has changed.

In application_controller.rb I have `protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

My form is like this (using slim)

```
form#spreadsheet-form{
  action='/submit_spreadsheet'
}
  textarea.spreadsheet-input{
    name='instructions'
    style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
  }
  br
  input.spreadsheet-submit{
    type="submit"
    value="submit"
  }
```

The main issue in my eyes is why this doesn't raise an error. In the past I've had to include a hidden input with `form_authencicity_token` as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is something to do with the ***Rails 5*** changed the `protect_from_forgery` execution order. From this [*blog*](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/06/rails-5-default-protect-from-forgery-prepend-false.html)

**What**

If we generate a brand new Rails application in *Rails 4.x* then `application_controller` will look like this.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Looking it at the code it does not look like `protect_from_forgery` is a `before_action` call but in reality that’s what it is. Since protect_from_forgery is a before_action call it should follow the order of how other `before_action` are executed. But this one is special in the sense that `protect_from_forgery` is executed first in the series of `before_action` no matter where `protect_from_forgery` is mentioned. Let’s see an example.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_user
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

In the above case even though protect_from_forgery call is made after `load_user`, the protection execution happens first. And we can’t do anything about it. We can’t pass any option to stop Rails from doing this.

***Rails 5*** changes this behavior by introducing a boolean option called prepend. Default value of this option is `false`. What it means is, now `protect_from_forgery` gets executed in order of call. Of course, this can be overridden by passing `prepend: true` as shown below and now protection call will happen first just like *Rails 4.x*.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_user
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
end
```

**Why**

*There isn’t any real advantage in forcing `protect_from_forgery` to be the first filter in the chain of filters to be executed*. On the flip side, there are cases where output of other `before_action` should decide the execution of `protect_from_forgery`. Let’s see an example.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate
  protect_from_forgery unless: -> { @authenticated_by.oauth? }

  private
    def authenticate
      if oauth_request?
        # authenticate with oauth
        @authenticated_by = 'oauth'.inquiry
      else
        # authenticate with cookies
        @authenticated_by = 'cookie'.inquiry
      end
    end
end
```

Above code would fail in *Rails 4.x*, as `protect_from_forgery`, though called after `:authenticate`, actually gets executed before it. Due to which we would not have `@authenticated_by` set properly.

Whereas in ***Rails 5***, `protect_from_forgery` gets executed after `:authenticate` and gets skipped if authentication is oauth

Comment: thanks very much for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, the `prepend: true` simply has no effects. I will have to mess with it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Is the authenticity token present on your form when you inspect it? Which point is `protect_from_forgery` inserted in your application?

Rails 4=>5 changed the default behaviour to be inserted wherever in the chain it is called, opposed to the previous where it was called first. If you want it to be called before any other action, try using the `prepend: true` flag.

Comment: The authenticity token is not in the generated HTML. `protect_from_forgery` is located in application_controller.rb as I stated in the question. I tried adding `prepend: true` but it had no effect. In other words, thanks but this didn't work.